# Regex working in RedHat is not giving any result in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

My goal is to match specific files from specific sub directories. I have the following folder structure

```
`-- data
    |-- a
    |-- a.txt
    |-- b
    |-- b.txt
    |-- c
    |-- c.txt
    |-- d
    |-- d.txt
    |-- e
    |-- e.txt
    |-- org-1
    |   |-- a.org
    |   |-- b.org
    |   |-- org.txt
    |   |-- user-0
    |   |   |-- a.txt
    |   |   |-- b.txt
```

I am trying to list the files only inside the data directory.
I am able to get the correct result using the following command in RHEL

```
find  ./testdir/ -iwholename "*/data/[!/].txt"
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
```

If I run the same command in Ubuntu it is not working.

Can anyone please tell me why it is not working in Ubuntu ?

**Edit:**

After some tests I realized that as per my post it is working properly in both RHEL and Ubuntu. The problem lies somewhere else. The file which I have in my Ubuntu system are data files.

It is very strange that for these file types it is not listing both in RHEL and Ubuntu.

```
[supratik@testserver ~]$ ls testprog/data/
a.txt  data.dat

[supratik@testserver ~]$ file testprog/data/a.txt
testprog/data/a.txt: ASCII text

[supratik@testserver ~]$ file testprog/data/data.dat
testprog/data/data.dat: data

[supratik@testserver ~]$ find  ./testprog/ -iwholename "*/data/[!/].txt"
./testprog/data/a.txt

[supratik@testserver ~]$ find  ./testprog/ -iwholename "*/data/[!/].dat"
```

Comment: What happens in Ubuntu ? What are a,b,c,d etc ?

Comment: In Ubuntu I just get a prompt back, I don't get the list of files.
"a, b, c,d, e" are also files. I created them using touch for testing.

Comment: Did you try using `ls` piped into `grep -E` instead?

Comment: I think you're using a glob rather than a regex...

Comment: @mbrownnyc I have a many sub directories inside the data folder. So ls will work for me, but find will be much cleaner solution. I am surprised why find is not listing the binary files or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this on CentOS 5.6,6.0 and Ubuntu 9.04,10.04 and 11.04 and I get the same answer on all of them viz

```
find  ./testdir/ -iwholename "*/data/[!/].txt"
./testdir/data/c.txt
./testdir/data/d.txt
./testdir/data/a.txt
./testdir/data/e.txt
./testdir/data/b.txt
```

You can get similar results with

```
Find ./testdir/data/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt'
```

Comment: @lain Please check my edited reply on my post. Can you please tell me why I am getting this strange result? I can not use -maxdepth because I have sub folders inside it which I am filtering out by multiple regex with -iwholename.